# fastapi server not responding

Tags: python, fastapi

I have no responses of the server when I request the API.
When I request it with thunder client, it just show the progress forever.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI 
import uvicorn
from typing import Union
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional
import couchdb
import requests
import json
from fastapi import Request 
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
import recaptcha_2 as _recaptcha_2
import fastapi.responses as _responses 
import random as _random
import captcha 
from captcha.image import ImageCaptcha

api = FastAPI() #on instancie 

@api.get('/get')
async def get():
    return {'True'}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(api, host= '127.0.0.1', port= 2222)
```

Thanks for answering

Comment: You're returning a static value, so you don't need an async function

Comment: running your example code and then going to `http://localhost:2222/get` returns me the json response as expected,. `INFO:     127.0.0.1:63059 - "GET /get HTTP/1.1" 200 OK` so based on your example the issue is not with your fast api code.

Comment: It's the problem.. There are no mistakes on the code... But it doesn't respond when I request it

Comment: First: Why are all the extra imports here? Is this the actual code you're running? How do you run the application? What error message do you get back (i.e. what does "not responding" mean - what does your browser/`curl` tell you?) Does anything change if you use a different port? Does `uvicorn <modulename>:api` give you a different result?